# How to create an array from inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, input

I created multiplied input fields:

```
<div class="form-text-field first-name field-group">
    <input data-index="1" type="text" id="firstName1" class="signup-input firstName" name="first[1]" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="form-text-field email field-group">
    <input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value ignore" name="email[1]"  placeholder="${message(code:"signup.redesign.placeholder.eg.email")}"/>
    <span class="common-sprite disNone sign-up-cross first clone"></span>
</div>
```

I have a code in the JS file which clone every input.

I have to create arrays from the values of the inputs (one for the email, and one for the first name).

Here is the function:

```
var arrEmail = []
var arrName = []
function add() {
    var obj = {};
    var partner = {}
    $('.email input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        obj[this.data-index] = this.value;
    });
    arrEmail.push(obj)
    $('.first-name input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        partner[this.data-index] = this.value;
    });
    arrName.push(partner)
    console.log(arrEmail[0])
}
```

I didn't succeed to get the arrays in this code. How do I fix it?

Comment: identifiers can't have minus sign, try to use `$(this).data('index');`

Comment: use `$(this).data('index')`  or `$(this).attr('data-index')`

Comment: You can use map like  `arrEmail = $('.email input[type="text"], .first-name input[type="text"]').map(function({
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();`

Comment: Do you need the arrays index? Why don't you push elements to array? Like `$('.email input[type="text"]').each(function(){ arrEmail.push($(this).val()); });`.

Comment: @kmsdev- it's work:) but for some reason I got null value when I try to send the arr in ajax (data: {email: arrEmail, name: arrName})

Comment: @saritrotshild  pass dada with JSON.stringify(arrEmail)  . it will pass data in text format

Comment: @kmsdev- can you explain me why I have to?

Comment: @kmsdev- I have to pass it as a string of arrays

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes.

1. Wrong syntax in line `$('.email input[type="text"]').each(function({`. You forgot to close bracket.
2. I don't understand why you tried get value this strange manner. You included jQuery. Use it!

I fix your code.

```
var arrEmail = [];
var arrName = [];

function add() {
    var obj = {};
    var partner = {};
    $('.email input[type="text"]').each(function(item) {
        obj[$(this).data('index')] = $(this).val();
    });
    arrEmail.push(obj);

    $('.first-name input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        obj[$(this).data('index')] = $(this).val();
    });
    arrName.push(obj);

    console.log(arrEmail);
    console.log(arrName);
}

$('#test').on('click', add);
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6q4ohzja/1/)

**Upd #1**

Haven't shown all conditions. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).data('index')` instead of `this.data-index`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with a single array:

```
var myUsers= [];//this might be object that you store the user information

$('.first-name input[type="text"]').each(function(item) {
    //first create the user information
    var myUser = new Object();
    myUser.Username = $(this).val();
    myUser.Email= $(this).next().val();

    //then add the user information to the myUsers array
     myUsers.push(myUser );
});
```